# SimpleXML Parse Children With Same Name and Attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I can't figure out how to parse an xml file like this using simpleXML.

```
<root>
 <movies>
    <movie cast="some,actors" description="Nice Movie">Pacific Rim</movie>
    <movie cast="other,actors" description="Awesome Movie">Atlantic Rim</movie>
</movies>
</root>
```

Expected output am looking at is something like

```
Pacific Rim [cast="some,actors"],[description="Nice Movie"]
Atlantic Rim [cast="other,actors"],[description="Awesome Movie"]
```

I have tried

```
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);
foreach($xml->movies as $movie)
{
  echo $movie->cast." ".$movie->description;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried restructuring your xml so it's not like <movies><movie><cast>names</cast></movie></movies>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$xml_string = '<root>
 <movies>
    <movie cast="some,actors" description="Nice Movie">Pacific Rim</movie>
    <movie cast="other,actors" description="Awesome Movie">Atlantic Rim</movie>
</movies>
</root>';

/* Expected result: */

/* Pacific Rim [cast="some,actors"],[description="Nice Movie"] */
/* Atlantic Rim [cast="other,actors"],[description="Awesome Movie"] */

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
foreach($xml->movies->movie as $movie)
{
    $name = (string) $movie;
    $attributes = $movie->attributes();
    print $name.' '.'[cast="'.$attributes['cast'].
          '"],[description="'.$attributes['description']."\"]\n";
}
```

In addition, you can access attributes directly with this syntax (without calling `attributes()`):

```
print $movie["cast"] . " " . $movie["description"];
```